# External internet emulation needed

Tags: internet-connection

I am setting up a game server (OpenSim) and I am needing to login to the server from an outside vantage point to do some testing from outside my home network.

I will be doing this on a Windows XP Home running on a laptop.

What will I need in order to get this "seeing my game server" from the internet without having to run off to a friends house to access it from their IP?

Comment: Wow, you're going to need quite some drives and spare time if you're going to emulate tha internets itself!

Comment: Remote desktop to your friends PC (go to my PC), login from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a remote access solution. The common choices are:

- Remote Desktop (built-in to Windows XP Pro but not Home, requires a port forwarded through the router)
- VNC (installable, requires a port forwarded through the router)
- Proprietary remote access solutions such as TeamViewer, LogMeIn, GoToMyPC, etc. (installable, doesn't require any port forwarding).

See the question "[What's the best remote desktop application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application)" for more information and recommendations.

Comment: Nice, complete answer